# Flutter: Cómo asignar un valor por defecto a una lista en el constructor de una clase?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy aprendiendo Flutter.

Es posible asignar valores por defecto a una lista en un constructor de una clase?

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
class MapState {

  final bool readyMap;
  final List<Marker> allMarkers;

  MapState({ 
    this.readyMap = false, 
    this.allMarkers
  });

  MapState copyWith({
    bool readyMap,
    List<Marker> allMarkers
  }) => MapState(
    readyMap: readyMap ?? this.readyMap,
    allMarkers: allMarkers ?? this.allMarkers
  );
}
```

Cómo puedo hacer que "allMarkers" por defecto sea "allMarkers = []" **para evitar que sea null** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solamente ajusta el constructor de la siguiente manera:

```dart
  MapState({ 
    this.readyMap = false, 
   List<Marker> allMarkers
  }): this.allMarkers = allMarkers != null? allMarkers : <Marker>[];
```

Comment: Esta respuesta sigue estando actualizada? Tengo el mismo problema pero me da error

Comment: hola, podrías comentar que error te sale o si es posible crear una pregunta con más detalles para revisarla

Comment: Básicamente me dice que `allMarkers` no puede tener un valor `null`. Lo solucioné marcando la propiedad como `List<Marker>?`